# steps to perform average case analysis

Tags: algorithm-analysis, average-case

What are the steps required to perform average case analysis?

Basically, how do you attempt average case analysis?

There exists a series of steps that need to be taken to perform it right?

I am just not sure what these are (and can't seem to find any good material explaining how to do it).

Comment: This is a very broad question, and in fact, textbooks have been written about this very topic.

Comment: Which textbook(s)? I have found little so far.

Comment: CLRS, Sedgewick, .... there are dozens, literally. If you haven't found one, you haven't searched. Google "Algorithm analysis textbook" for starters.